# Force Joda-Time date parsing to follow strictly the standard ISO 8601 pattern of YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to parse date string and convert to local date. For parsing date I am expecting string to be in format of "yyyy-MM-dd". I have used following code to parse date string.

I am using **java 11**

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

     public class Test {
    
          public static void main(String[] args) {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter= new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        .toFormatter();
                String dateAsString="20-08-09"; //should not parsed to date
                LocalDate localDate=null;
                 try {
                      localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(dateAsString);
                 }catch (IllegalArgumentException | UnsupportedOperationException e){
                     System.out.println("Invalid date "+dateAsString);
                 }
                System.out.println(" local date "+localDate.toString()); // output local date 0020-08-09
            }
    }
```

Above code works for most of the cases except If I pass date in format 'yy-MM-dd' it also consider as valid and  parse to local date.
How do I force date parsing to follow 'yyyy-MM-dd' pattern only.

Comment: `formatter.parseLocalDate`? Is that actually compiling for you? In which version of Java does DateTimeFormatter have such a method?

Comment: Try this  `localDate = LocalDate.from(formatter.parse(dateAsString));`

Comment: @k314159 I have java 11

Comment: [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) does not have a method `parseLocalDate`. The code in the question does not compile. You are using Joda-Time, right?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  year wih 2 digits is parsing successfully. It does not go to catch block. If I pass string '20-08-09' it will parse it and create date  0020-08-09.

Comment: @Zeister are you sure you're using java.time.DateTimeFormatter? You must be using someone else's class, because the standard one doesn't have such a method. Check your import statement.

Comment: @andrewJames Sorry for confusion. Yes it is from Joda time. I have updated question with imports

Comment: @Zeister With `LocalDate.parse("20-08-09", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))` it **would fail** as expected according to the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`. Now I see that you're using `joda.time`, it poses the question do you really need an external dependency especially when it's possible to achieve desired behavior with standard `java.time` classes?

Comment: If you can replace joda with `java.time`, then there's no need for all that convoluted syntax to build a formatter. Just use the predefined `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.

Comment: If you need to keep Joda Time, take a look at [How to parse four digit year only (with Joda Time)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612150/12567365). For example: `.appendFixedDecimal(org.joda.time.DateTimeFieldType.year(), 4)`. But now would be a good time to move to `java.time`, perhaps. Pun intended.